# java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException:

Tags: java

```
  System.out.printf("%s%13s%\n", "TarrifType", "AnnualCost");
  System.out.printf("%s%d.%n", "String" 243.08);

    Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '
at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
at ModelComparison.main(ModelComparison.java:12)
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bugs..

```
System.out.printf("%s%13s\n", "TarrifType", "AnnualCost");
System.out.printf("%s%f\n", "String", 243.08);
```

http://ideone.com/USOx1

Answer (score 32):

What's wrong is the `%\n` in the first line. Note that the `%` is a special character in a format string that indicates that a format specifier follows. The `\n` after the `%` is not a valid format specifier.

If you wanted to print a percent sign, then double it in the format string: `%%`

If you wanted to print a newline, then use `%n`, not `%\n`.

Comment: Or, just use `\n` when you want a newline. Format specifiers are not required.

Answer (score 9):

The problem in your format string is that you mixed two ways of doing newline: `%n` and `\n`. The former tells the formatter to put a newline in whatever format the platform requires, whereas the latter puts in just a literal newline char. But what you wrote was `%\n`, which means you're escaping the newline char, and that's what's blowing up.

You also forgot a comma between "String" and 243.08 in the second call. And btw, `%d` formats an integer, so you probably don't want it if you're trying to print 243.08.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Android) there was an error in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="cashback">10% cashback</string>
```

When I tried to get `getString(R.string.cashback)`, I received this exception. To fix it, replace `%` with `%%`.

Answer (score 0):

If a string desired to format in Kotlin, the following code snippet can be used.

In the string.xml:

```
<string name = "exampleString"><![CDATA[<font color=#3177a3> String_1: <b>%%s</b><br> String_2: <b>%%s</b><br> String_3: <b>%%s</b></font>]]></string>
```

In the main code:

```
val format = String.format(getString(R.string.exampleString),
            value1,
            value2,
            value3
        )
```